# How to solve this email sending error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I solve this email sending error in codeigniter?

```
220 smtp.googlemail.com ESMTP g7sm4210473pgr.52 - gsmtp hello: 
250-smtp.googlemail.com at your service, [49.34.9.27] 
250-SIZE 35882577 
250-8BITMIME 
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 
250-PIPELINING 
250-CHUNKING 
250 SMTPUTF8 

Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. 

Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials g7sm4210473pgr.52 - gsmtp 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method. 
Date: Thu, 14 Nov 2019 04:57:55 +0100 From: "RK Dream Homes" <> Return-Path: <> To: rushiid123@gmail.com Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Property=20Management?= Reply-To: <> User-Agent: CodeIgniter X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal) Message-ID: <5dccd0c3c0a25> Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5dccd0c3c0a3c"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_5dccd0c3c0a3c Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Comment: did you read error given from google smtp server. Clearily mentioned `Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method`.

Comment: `Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted`

Answer (score 0):

You must check few things (Gmail SMTP)

1. Verify Email and Password are correct.
2. Enable Less Secure App [Here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)
3. Enable Display Unlock Captcha  [here](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)
4. Use Host : `smtp.gmail.com`
5. Use Port : `587` or `465` as per `SSL` or `TLS` setting

Also check `newline` as per below

```
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below configuration in CI and make sure it's correct.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'apple@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['starttls'] = false;
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['smtp_timeout']='30';
$config['newline']="\r\n";
```

Also, please ensure that gmail is allowed to access by another app.

There are 2 steps to check in gmail account.

1. Allow less secure app access. 
   https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
2. Allow access to your Google account. 
   https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: I am having the same problem. But from my localhost machine I can send the mail and from my real subdomain site of the server I cannot. Is there any solution to send mail from subdomain?

Comment: the issue is causing by authorization, I think. Have you tried to 2 steps above?

Comment: Now I am using mailjet for sending mail and it is working well.